# Extract values from a string with Python

Tags: python, regex

I send a POST request that returns me as a string response with the following structure.: |hiddenField|field_name|field_value|

How can I do in Python to get these values, field_name and field_value?

I tried using regular expression, but I could not.

> |hiddenField|__VIEWSTATE|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|512|hiddenField|__VIEWSTATE1|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|512|hiddenField|__VIEWSTATE2|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|512|

Comment: use `your_string.split("|")[2]` and `[3]`

Comment: err, there seems to be 4 types contained in this string. `hiddenField`, `__VIEWSTATE`, some long text string, and a number. Which information were you trying to collect, and what format where you trying to get it into?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can parse your data using `regex` like this example:

I assume your data is:

```
a = "|hiddenField|__VIEWSTATE|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|512|hiddenField|__VIEWSTATE1|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|512|hiddenField|__VIEWSTATE2|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|512|"
```

Then you can do:

```
import re

obj = re.findall('\|hiddenField|\|(.*?)\|\d+\|', a)

final = {k[0]:k[1] for k in [k.split('|') for k in obj if k != '']}

for k in final.items():
    print(k)
```

Output:

```
('__VIEWSTATE1', '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')
('__VIEWSTATE', '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')
('__VIEWSTATE2', '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')
```

However, if you want to parse all your data like `|hiddenField|field_name|field_value|digits` you can do:

```
import re

obj = re.findall('\|hiddenField|\|(.*?)\|(\d+)\|', a)

final = {k[0]:{'field_value': k[1], 'digits': k[2]} for k in [k[0].split("|") + [k[1]] for k in obj if k != ('','')]}

for k in final.items():
    print(k)
```

Output:

```
('__VIEWSTATE', {'field_value': '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', 'digits': '512'})
('__VIEWSTATE2', {'field_value': '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', 'digits': '512'})
('__VIEWSTATE1', {'field_value': 'AQAAAAEAAAAHAwAAAAABAAAABAAAAAQvQlNBLk5ldEZvcmNlLk1vZGVsLkNvcmUuRW50aXRpZXMuR3J1cG9Qcm9tb3RvcmECAAAACQQAAAANAwUEAAAAL0JTQS5OZXRGb3JjZS5Nb2RlbC5Db3JlLkVudGl0aWVzLkdydXBvUHJvbW90b3JhBgAAABw8SWRHcnVwb3Byb20+a19fQmFja2luZ0ZpZWxkFTxOb21lPmtfX0JhY2tpbmdGaWVsZCA8Q2RVc3VhcmlvR2VzdG9yPmtfX0JhY2tpbmdGaWVsZCA8SWRVc3VhcmlvR2VzdG9yPmtfX0JhY2tpbmdGaWVsZBo8RHRDcmlhY2FvPmtfX0JhY2tpbmdGaWVsZBg8RG9taW5pbz5rX19CYWNraW5nRmllbGQAAQEDAwEFDlN5c3RlbS5EZWNpbWFsD1N5c3RlbS5EYXRlVGltZQIAAAABMgYFAAAAEUdSVVBPIFBSSU1FQ09SQkFOBgYAAAAKMDAw', 'digits': '512'})
```

Comment: If the text has for example `|| hiddenField | __EVENTARGUMENT |`. Is it possible to get only where __VIEWSTATE appears? [text](https://justpaste.it/13z6x)

Comment: Please edit your question and post an example of your data.

Answer (score 4):

If you can assume the data will consistently be in the given format, you can convert it to a dictionary mapping field names to field values with the following function:

```
def parse(big_string_blob):
  split_input = big_string_blob.split("|")     # (1)
  field_names = split_input[2::4]              # (2)
  field_values = split_input[3::4]             # (3)
  return dict(zip(field_names, field_values))  # (4)
```

1: Converts the text string into a list of strings separated by the `|` character. See [string.split](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split)
2. Creates a list containing every fourth element of `split_input` starting from the 3rd element. These correspond to the field names.
3. Creates a list containing every fourth element of `split_input` starting from the 4th element. These correspond to the field values.
4. Creates a dictionary mapping the elements in the first list as keys to the corresponding elements in the second list. See [zip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip).

You can also play around with it here: https://repl.it/Fyog/0

Comment: If in your String you have other keys and you just want __viewstate you can do: `print {k:v for k,v in items.items() if '__VIEWSTATE' in k}`

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following too. It will only take words that begin with `__`

```
obj = [x.group() for x in re.finditer('__.*?\|\d+\|', input)]
final = {k[0]:k[1] for k in [k.split('|') for k in obj if k != '']}
for k in final.items():
    print(k)
```